# How to use GraphQL and NestJS to parse node related data to dynamic tree structure?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

For this departments JSON data

```json
{
    "departments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "department 1",
            "parent_id": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "department 2",
            "parent_id": "1" 
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "department 3",
            "parent_id": "1" 
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "department 4",
            "parent_id": "2" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Now want to get it and parse to a multiple children GraphQL structure with NestJS.

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "department 1",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "department 2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "department 4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "department 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since the department relations are very large, the children node is also dynamically. How to create an `@ObjectType` and parse the origin JSON data to the new tree mode?